# Adding and Displaying Array Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var reset = function ()
    {
        var p = parseFloat($("#IA").val());
        var q = parseFloat($("#IB").val());
        var m = parseFloat($("#CGCD").val());
        var aR = [];

        aR += ["GCD(" + p + "," + q + ")=" + m];

        document.getElementById("PGCD").innerHTML = aR + "\n";

        document.getElementById("IA-error").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("IB-error").innerHTML="";

        $("#IA").focus();
    };
```

The code above is only for a 'reset' function, a part of additional code (not present), the purpose which is to find the Greatest Common Denominator, GCD.

My 'reset' function is connected to a button, #reset, the purpose of which is to do four things:

1. add and store the string **GCD(p,q)=m** to the array 'aR'; p/q/m are variable stand-ins for the values of the input text areas #IA, #IB, and #CGCD (the GCD of #IA and #IB);
2. display the array 'aR' in a text-area #PGCD *each* time the reset button is clicked; this is why I used an array;
3. clear the two input text areas #IA and #IB;
4. clear the one output text area;

As it stands, all four objectives are completed successfully, with one exception: for the second objective, only the *most recent* GCD calculation is outputted; none of the previous calculations output.

I cannot get the array to list the different saved calculations within it. I think (?) the new calculations are being added to the array, but I am not sure.

I've tried a 'for' statement, and an 'if' statement, neither of which worked. I don't know whether I coded it wrong, or if it wasn't the right solution for my issue.

I tried to search the forums (here) for a solution, but was unable to find one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you are describing, I believe your problem is that you are attempting to use += to add elements to an array. You should use

```
aR.push("GCD(" + p + "," + q + ")=" + m);
```

The += operator is used for addition of a value to itself as well as string concatenation.

Edit: per comments below, the main issue was declaration of aR as a local variable. It needs to be either global or declared within the same scope.

Comment: I am trying to add and display new calculations as they are entered. Currently, I can only display the most recent calculation. I did add your code into it, and it did not change the output. I guess the questions I have is: are the calculations being added to the array 'aR', and if so, why is the array not displaying all calculations saved? Additional: I added +"\n" after m variable, in trying to add a break to the next line in the output; nothing has changed.

Comment: I just realized something. Your array variable, aR, is declared locally inside your function. That means that you are starting over with an empty array every time. Either pull your declaration and initialization of aR and make it global, or enclose what you have into one "scope." There are a few ways to accomplish the latter, but just to see if your script works I would make aR global for now.

Comment: It worked! I made the array 'aR' global (outside of all my functions) and it worked. You were correct, the array was only local to the function 'reset' and so when the button #reset was clicked again, it overlapped my previous calculation placed in the array. Putting the array global allowed for the recent calculation to be added and saved without be overlapped, hence allowing more than one to be added (and later, displayed). THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR HELP, thesentiment!

Comment: Just a small favor, can you mark as answered? Thanks in advance!